# FtpWebRequest Azure An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, filezilla

I am using Windows Azure Cloud.

I am trying to list files from an FTP site. The software works fine on my local machine, however, I get a popup about my Windows Firewall. Using Windows Azure Cloud, is there a way I can add a firewall rule for an FTP Web Request?

My customer's FTP server supports active configuration only:

IMPORTANT!! Please ensure that you are in “Active” mode as “Passive” mode will not work. Active FTP requires the clients firewall to allow traffic above > 1023 from port 20 & 21. Port 20 is the data communication port that most people forget to allow. Check both hardware firewalls and software firewalls like (XP firewall).

Here is the error:

```
System.Net.FtpClient.FtpCommandException: Cannot open data connection.
```

Here is my code:

```html
        private FtpClient GetFtpClient()
        {
            FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient();
            ftp.Host = m_FtpUrl;
            ftp.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoActive;
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(m_FtpUserName, m_FtpPassword);
            ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/Orders/Archive/");
            return ftp;
        }

        private List<string> ListFiles()
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            FtpClient ftp = GetFtpClient();
            foreach (FtpListItem item in ftp.GetListing(ftp.GetWorkingDirectory()))
            {
                if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
                    lines.Add(item.Name);
            }

            return lines;
        }
```

I have allowed ports 20, 21 and 1023 in my endpoints:

[image]

When I use FileZilla, here is the response:

```
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of trade.marketplace.buy.com
Status: Connecting to 209.67.181.90:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PORT 209,67,181,90,23,189
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678825/open-active-ftp-connection-from-azure-vm

Comment: Thanks for the post. I added the endpoints. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, in my linked question I forgot to read an important point "Unless you are unlucky and using .NET Framework FTPWebRequest.". So, I think you cannot do what you want.